# How should you deal with people who suddenly post angry comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

I don't know how I triggered this user, but for me it was really a kinda funny thing to happen. In this situation, what should you do?

This user answered a question but with just a link; I suggested that putting some examples would be great for his answer, but suddenly this guy started to rage, as you can see in the image below. Now I won't blame him - maybe he just had a hard time or anything else - but officially, these things should not be happening, right? What can we do?

[image]

Comment: Downvote (to enable =>), flag as VLQ (where the review queue comments have a default "link-only answer" option), move on.

Comment: also flag the comment(s) as "unfriendly / rude".

Comment: roblox didn't choose prisonlife, prisonlife chose roblox :) Seriously, you don't have the tools to actually "deal" with these kind of people here. Flag them as rude and disengage. Let moderators do their job.

Comment: Utterly disappointed about the amount of raging. I at least expected pages full of rude comments. Please do better next time. ;)

Comment: _"Vaporizing [users] from existence"_ is probably against StackExchange policies, although I cannot quickly find the relevant discussion on Meta.

Comment: @rene Wowow bro, chill man :D Just chill :D

Comment: Don't mimic me man XD